# Can find the registry of MSBuild 15.0

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, registry

I have a old project, which is created by Visual Studio 2015, and I use a bat file to get the registry of MSBuild 14.0 in this project build event. Now I have to update my project to Visual Studio 2017, so I need to update the bat file to get the MSbuild 15.0, but I could not fins it.

In Visual Studio 2015:
The registry path is:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0`

The value is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin
```

But for Visual Studio 2017, I could not find the registry path.

How I get the registry value again for Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How I get the registry value again for Visual Studio 2017?

You should to read following thread:

[vswhere](https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere):

> Over the years Visual Studio could be discovered using registry keys,
>   but with recent changes to the deployment and extensibility models a
>   new method is needed to discover possibly more than once installed
>   instance. These changes facilitate a smaller, faster default install
>   complimented by on-demand install of other workloads and components.
>
> vswhere is designed to be a redistributable, single-file executable
>   that can be used in build or deployment scripts to find where Visual
>   Studio - or other products in the Visual Studio family - is located.
>   For example, if you know the relative path to MSBuild, you can find
>   the root of the Visual Studio install and combine the paths to find
>   what you need.
>
> vswhere is included with the installer as of Visual Studio 2017
>   version 15.2 and later, and can be found at the following location:
>   %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe.

And you use command like the following to find the latest version installed:

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims=: " %%i in (`vswhere -latest -requires Microsoft.Component.MSBuild`) do (
  if /i "%%i"=="installationPath" set InstallDir=%%j
)

if exist "%InstallDir%\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" (
  "%InstallDir%\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" %*
)
```

Hope this helps.